# Merge two tables into one pivot chart excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot-table, vlookup, excel-2007

Having two tables with the following data (with 0 representing sad and 1 happy)
I need to have one graph for the two tables.
The IDs are unique for each table.

I tried implementing it as two different pivot tables or as one regular table with a relationship but didn't succeed.
Using Excel.

Is it the right approach? How can I merge both tables into one pivot chart?
Maybe with vlookup?

Table 1 - group A:

| ID | happy/ sad |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | 0 |
| 456 | 1 |
| 789 | 0 |

Table 2 - group B:

| ID | happy/ sad |
| --- | --- |
| 111 | 1 |
| 444 | 1 |
| 888 | 0 |

Comment: Why a pivot chart? I don't see where `vlookup` will help here. What are you charting? If you don't want to combine your data, then is it okay to count them as combined? If it's simply counts, then perhaps just use a `COUNTIF` formula. Like `countif(range1, 1) + countif(range2, 1)` would represent all your Happy counts.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Isolated.
I used four different countIf and made a new chart with the answers and then a graph

Comment: Mimi, if @Isolated or anyone else has answered your question you should accept the answer and award the points.  If not, either answer your own question or delete the question.  See "Respond to feedback after posting" on https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: This is not an answer dont give you thanks as an answer

Answer (score 0):

A curious feature of the `IFERROR()` function is that, even in legacy Excel, it can be used to stack data, e.g.
[image: screenshot illustrating how IFERROR() function may be used to combine data]

such that the `A8:B13` range could be used as the source data for your combined chart.

(being an [array formula](https://exceljet.net/glossary/array-formula), the combined source will not grow with changes in the size of your tables but, in your context, where I imagine each table is a specific population, I would imagine that they are static once tabulated)